# How to convert \u009

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

im tryng to convert Ba\u009aka Voda to its correct characters using html_entity_decode

```
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_COMPAT);
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_QUOTES );
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_NOQUOTES);
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_HTML401);
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_XML1);
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_XHTML);
    echo html_entity_decode("Ba&#x009;aka Voda\n", ENT_HTML5);
```

Response is always:

`Ba aka Voda`

expected result should be : Baška Voda

what im doing wrong?

Comment: _“what im doing wrong?”_ - well for starters, you _say_ that you wanted to replace `\u009`, but then _that_ is not actually contained in any of your example data to begin with …

Comment: ya sorry i already replaced "\u009" with &#x009; because i've read in another post that this should be done before html_entity_decode.

html_entity_decode("Ba\u009aka Voda") did just respond "Ba\u009aka Voda"

Answer (score 0):

Use `mb_convert_encoding()` in combination with `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$input = "Baška Voda";

$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $input);


echo $output; // Baška Voda
```

Comment: This function `mb_ereg_replace` could be consider in your solution ?